# (g)awk: use GNU's date within system()

Tags: shell, awk

Inside a shell script, I want to modify a CSV file (with "|" as field separator) having one column (the eight) with dates as values.

More precisely, I want to increase each date by one day:

10/06/2018 becomes 10/07/2018

So, I'm trying to use GNU's coreutils 'date' command (in a Linux Mint environment) within gawk's system(), but my output is all wrong (just one column instead of the whole file and with one single value repeated).

```
awk -i inplace -F'|' -v OFS='|' '$8=system("date -d " $8+1days " +%m/%d/%y")' file.csv
```

Since, as justly pointed out in the comments, 'date' is not part of Bash but an external command, should I still be using system()?

Comment: `date` is an external command, unrelated to `bash`.

Comment: Also, what's your date format?  If 10/07/2018 is one day later than 10/06/2018, then it doesn't seem you're really using `%d/%m/%y`. Let's take the opportunity to switch to ISO8601 dates. Party like it's 1988!

Comment: Also note that usage and options of the `date` command vary by operating system. If you want a solution that will work in YOUR operating system, it would be better to include what operating system that is, since the list answers will necessarily be more limited.

Comment: I'm working on a UNI EN 28601 format, but since date (as far as I know) only accepts mm/dd/yyyy, I converted that one with a previous command... Just forgot to change it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're using `gawk` you don't need a system call

```
$ awk -i inplace 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} 
                  {split($8,a,"/"); 
                   $8=strftime("%m/%d/%Y", mktime(a[3]" "a[1]" "a[2]" 00 00 00")+24*60*60)}1' file
```

Comment: Hmm, must be cleared up as the OP has a different format in his code wrt what he writes. But it is clear that `date` translates `aa/bb/yyyy` as 'mm/dd/yyyy` and not `dd/mm/yyyy`

Answer (score 0):

The `+1 days` needs to be part of the input to `system`, and as such, quoted. It also needs to be quoted at the shell level, too.

```
awk -i inplace -F'|' -v OFS='|' '$8=system("date -d \""$8" +1 day\" +%d/%m/%y")' file.csv
```